# > Prove that for $x \in \Bbb R^n$ the following holds. $B_r(x) = \bigcup_{i=i}^\infty \overline{B}_{r-1/n}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Prove that for $x \in \Bbb R^n$ the following holds. $B_r(x) = \bigcup_{i=i}^\infty \overline{B}_{r-1/n}(x)$, where $B$ and $\overline{B}$ denote the open and closed balls respectively.

$”\subset”$ Let $y \in B_r(x)$, then $d(x,y) < r$. Now this means that for some $k>0$, we have that $d(x,y) < r-k$. Now what we want to get is that $d(x,y) \le r- \frac{1}{n}$ since that would imply that $y \in \bigcup_{i=i}^\infty \overline{B}_{r-1/n}(x) $. From $d(x,y) \le r- \frac{1}{n} $ one has that $n > \frac{1}{r-d(x,y)}$ in order for it to hold so if I choose $k= \frac{1}{n_k}$, where $n_k > \frac{1}{r-d(x,y)}$ I get that $d(x,y) < r- \frac{1}{n_k}$, but I still end up with a strict inequality. What might I be missing here? I’m not sure there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $d(y,x)<r$, there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1n\leqslant r-d(x,y)$; in other words, $d(y,x)\leqslant r-\frac1n$. And therefore $y\in\overline{B_{r-1/n}(x)}$.

Comment: Intuitively I understand that since $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ we have that $\frac{1}{n} \le r - d(x,y)$, but somehow I feel that this is missing some information or rigor?

Comment: So $d(y,x) < r \implies r - d(y,x) > 0$, but it’s hard to follow any logical steps to get to $r - d(y,x) \ge \frac{1}{n}$, without some hand waving...

Comment: Concerning your first comment, I simply used the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Ordered_fields): if $\varepsilon>0$, then there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1n<\varepsilon$. I did not use limits *at all*. Concerning your second comment, are you claiming that applying the Archimedean property is “hand waving”?

Comment: Doesn’t the Archimidean property imply a strict inequality? Definitely not claiming that it is ”hand waving”...

Comment: Yes, it claims a strict inequality. But if $\frac1n<r-d(x,y)$, then *in particular* we have $\frac1n\leqslant r-d(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

If we know that $d(x,y) < r - k$ and we want to know that for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$,  $d(x,y) \leq r - \frac{1}{n}$, then showing that $$r - k \leq r - \frac{1}{n},$$ or equivalently
$$ \frac{1}{n} \leq k ,$$
would be enough to do the trick. So, we need more information about this supposed $k$. Try finding a value $k$ which satisfies $d(x,y) \leq r - k$. Notice that I'm using '$\leq$' and not '$<$'. For problems like this, I would find it helpful to draw a diagram containing $x$, $y$, $B_r(x)$, and $d(x,y)$.